reject submit title in submit input when non used value
I used html code like below for replace "send" word with "submit" in input element.
<input type="submit">Send

this happened (error screenshot):

but I want shows form input like below without uses value property:

I expected the "send" word  written after the end of the "input" close tag to be replace in the "input" title as submit title

I'm not sure what you are asking or need help with. What specifically is going wrong and what have you tried already to fix it?

@jaydev95 I was uploaded 2 picture with public signs. I can not speak better from this subject about errors. more work and more study for you.

Yo never put "Send" in the input element. See Closing HTML  tag issue and check the MDN docs for a solution.

The way you change the button text for an <input> type of "submit" is to set the value attribute of the import control
<input type="submit" value="Send">

The value "Send" will be sent to the server.
Alternatively, you could use a <button> element.

You can't simply change the type of an <input> to anything you like. You want to instead use a button element, setting the type to submit, and giving it the text you want, like:
<button type="submit">Send</button>

